# How to see when a SQL Server 2008 Certificate Object Expires (& other properties)

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssl

I have a SQL Server 2008 mirroring setup where CREATE CERTIFICATE was used to generate the SQL Certificate Objects to enable mirroring between workgroup-based servers.

Q. How can I view the expiration date and other properties of the existing certificate objects?  (I understand that these are SQL "Objects" as they don't show up in the usual MMC certificates console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write sql queries to get the expiration dates from sys.certificates

Please follow the Remus Rusanu's excellent posts on this topic.

http://rusanu.com/2008/10/25/replacing-endpoint-certificates-that-are-near-expiration/

http://rusanu.com/2008/11/26/replacing-service-certificates-that-are-near-expiration/

http://rusanu.com/2008/10/23/how-does-certificate-based-authentication-work/

Comment: Terrific - exactly what I needed, and so hard to find myself!  Thanks Sankar :)  Sorry I'm not at 15 yet, so can't vote up your answer myself :P

Comment: NP. Glad it was helpful :-)